# Generic Repository Linq2Sql impedence mismatch problem

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, repository-pattern, expression-trees

I am working on a repository pattern where the API look as follows:

```
var visitor = repository.Find(x => x.EmailAddress == credentials.EmailAddress &&
                              x.Password == credentials.Password);
```

where visitor is a domain object and x represents this domain object.  The method signature of the Find method on the repository is:

```
T Find(Func<T, bool> query);
```

This is all wonderful until I attempt to use this with Linq2Sql because linq2sql creates its own objects and as a result when I want to call:

```
context.visitors.FirstOrDefault(query);
```

there is a type mismatch because linq2sql expects a function of the type it created and not the function I am passing in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to start with you'll need to change your `Find` signature to:

```
T Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> query);
```

LINQ to SQL needs to have the logic as an expression tree instead of a plain delegate, otherwise it can't work out how to translate it into SQL.

Beyond that, I'm afraid it's not terribly clear - it sounds like you're not using the same domain classes for your repository and LINQ to SQL. Is that right? That sounds like a potential problem; at the very least it's going to make life pretty tricky.

Comment: Yes... I do not want to use the Linq2SQL classes as my domain objects because I may want to add behavior to my domain objects and I may also want to restrict the accessability of the members.

Comment: Adding behaviour is easy: the generated classes are *partial classes* which means you can add your own behaviour in a separate file, but still in the same class. You can specify property accessibility in the dbml file.

Comment: That certianly seems like a much simpler approach than transforming expression trees from one type into another.  I will go with that approach and restrict visibility and access through interfaces.